# Ignite UI - (jQuery) - Unable to add comment in a cell using ig.excel.WorksheetCellComment

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, infragistics, ignite-ui

I am trying to add a comment into a cell in a worksheet . The functionality works without error but in the excel it adds a blank comment section without text . Please help.

```
$("#input").on("change", function () {
    var excelFile,
        fileReader = new FileReader();

    $("#result").hide();

    fileReader.onload = function (e) {
        var buffer = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result);
        $.ig.excel.Workbook.load(buffer, function (workbook) {
            var column, row, newRow, cellValue, columnIndex, i,
                worksheet = workbook.worksheets(0),
                columnsNumber = 0,
                gridColumns = [],
                data = [],
                worksheetRowsCount;　

            var comment = new $.ig.excel.WorksheetCellComment();
            var formatted = new $.ig.excel.FormattedString("This is a comment");
            comment.Text = formatted;
            worksheet.rows(2).cells(4).comment(comment);
            saveWorkbook(workbook, "Formatting.xlsx");
        }, function (error) {
            $("#result").text("The excel file is corrupted.");
            $("#result").show(1000);
        });
    }

    if (this.files.length > 0) {
        excelFile = this.files[0];
        if (excelFile.type === "application/vnd.ms-excel" || excelFile.type === "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" || (excelFile.type === "" && (excelFile.name.endsWith("xls") || excelFile.name.endsWith("xlsx")))) {

            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(excelFile);
        } else {
            $("#result").text("The format of the file you have selected is not supported. Please select a valid Excel file ('.xls, *.xlsx').");
            $("#result").show(1000);
        }

        function saveWorkbook(workbook, name) {
            workbook.save({ type: 'blob' }, function (data) {
                saveAs(data, name);
            }, function (error) {
                alert('Error exporting: : ' + error);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Tried based on this link http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.1/ig.excel.WorksheetCellComment

Answer (score 3):

```
....
var comment = new $.ig.excel.WorksheetCellComment();
var formatted = new $.ig.excel.FormattedString("This is a comment");
// The $.ig.excel.WorksheetCellComment does not have .Text as a property
// See http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.1/ig.excel.WorksheetCellComment#methods:text
comment.text(formatted);
```

The comment is present in the excel file.

http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.1/ig.excel.WorksheetCellComment#methods:text

Comment: I see only a blank comment bubble , Text is not getting inserted. Can anyone suggest any.alternatives ...